# Talend workflow for importing multiple gzip file un-archiving and creating calculated field

Tags: etl, talend

I want to 1)read multiple gzip files from a path, 2)un-archive and 3)create a calculated field. So far i have been successful in doing 1 and 2. For 3, i thought that tMap will do the needful, however don't know why i am unable to connect the un-archive component with tMap.

[image]

Edit1:
I don't know why tdelemited and tMap have the error message showing?

[image]

below is the message i got
    Starting job Migration_1 at 09:36 04/04/2017.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3336
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
Job Migration_1 ended at 09:36 04/04/2017. [exit code=0]
```

Edit2: i tried with all suggested steps, yet it does not give me the required output and to my surprise there is no error message in the log to debug anything.

[image]
    Starting job Migration_1 at 12:36 04/04/2017.

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3463
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
Job Migration_1 ended at 12:36 04/04/2017. [exit code=0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tFileUnarchive will just unarchive the zip files, but you will still have to read the files contained in these zips. tFileUnarchive component does not provide this reading part.

After the tFileList-->tFileUnarchive subjob, you should have a file-reading subjob, such as :

```
tFileList--iterate-->tFileInput*-->tMap
```

tFileList should be set to read the repository where you extracted the gzip files.

Comment: from tfileUnarchieve, for connecting with tFileInputDelimited, 1) should i iterate or do OnComponentOk? 2) what should i use as 'File name/Stream'?

Comment: There will be two different subjobs. The first one for  unarchiving, the second one for reading files. So you'll have to put a OnSubJobOK link between the 2 tFileList components

Comment: for tFileInput-->tMap should i iterate or something else? it didn't give me any result. I have added the new screenshot and output message from talend

Comment: You have two warning signs on your components : pay attention to those warnings to solve your problem. 1 )Have you defined schema for your fileInput component  ? 2) you have to add an output after tMap.

Comment: I have added details after your suggestion. It's still not giving me desired output